# Azure Data Factory Tasks Queued

Tags: azure-data-factory

I've created a new ADF pipeline which is working well but gives me some concern over performance.

As an example - here's a task from the pipeline that copies a small blob from a container to another container in the same storage account:

[image]

Notice that it's queued for 58 seconds.

The pipeline uses "Managed Virtual Network" integration runtime because it makes use of Azure SQL Private Endpoints.

Any ideas why the copy data tasks are held at "Queued" for so long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned that your pipeline using "Managed Virtual Network" integration runtime, therefore, as per the [Activity execution time using managed virtual network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/managed-virtual-network-private-endpoint#activity-execution-time-using-managed-virtual-network):

> By design, Azure integration runtime in managed virtual network takes
> longer queue time than global Azure integration runtime as we are not
> reserving one compute node per data factory, so there is a warm up for
> each activity to start, and it occurs primarily on virtual network
> join rather than Azure integration runtime. For non-copy activities
> including pipeline activity and external activity, there is a 60
> minutes Time To Live (TTL) when you trigger them at the first time.
> Within TTL, the queue time is shorter because the node is already
> warmed up.

There is also 60 minutes time to Live(TTL) feature is available in "Managed Virtual Network" IR which shorten the queue time because the node is already warmed up, but **unfortunately Copy activity doesn't have TTL support yet.**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I wanted to be sure that something I’d done wasn’t causing it to be so slow.

Comment: my pipeline uses several copy data tasks to simply copy small text files between storage account containers. This means each pipeline run takes more than 5 minutes! Do you know if there's there a better way to achieve the same functionality within a pipeline?

Comment: Also, any word on when the copy task will support TTL please?

Comment: Hi @Rob, I request you to post your query as a new question instead in comment section so that it would be properly addressed by the community members.

Comment: The queue issue will be resolved if you use Azure IR instead of "Managed Virtual Network" IR. Not sure when the TTL support will be available for copy task. You can [raise the feature request](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/post/79b1327d-d925-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f06a4).

Comment: I have now posted the seconds question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70271588/data-factory-pipeline-copy-data-tasks-in-managed-vnet . My understanding is I can't use Azure IR if I need to access resources such as Azure SQL and Azure Storage Accounts through vnet integration

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to provide the required information there.

Comment: Copy activity does support TTL now, although feature is in Public Preview: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/managed-virtual-network-private-endpoint#time-to-live-preview