# Data Factory Pipeline Copy Data Tasks in Managed VNet

Tags: azure-data-factory

From the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70225191/azure-data-factory-tasks-queued) it can be seen that Copy Data tasks run slowly when using a "Managed Virtual Network" integration runtime. Does anyone know of an alternative or when performance of the copy task within a managed vnet ir is likely to be improved?

Answer (score 0):

As per [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance#self-hosted-integration-runtime-scalability) you can achieve higher performance by either scale up or scale out the Self-hosted IR.

•   You can scale up the self-hosted IR, by increasing the number of concurrent jobs that can run on a node.

Scale up works only if the processor and memory of the node are being less than fully utilized.

•   You can scale out the self-hosted IR, by adding more nodes (machines).

> when performance of the copy task within a managed vnet ir is likely
> to be improved?

Regarding above question, you can raise request feature [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/79b1327d-d925-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f06a4)

Comment: but it's not a self-hosted IR, its a "managed virtual network" IR

Answer (score 0):

The feature to improve copy activity performance with Managed VNET IR is now in Public Preview. You need to enable Copy Compute Scale and set a higher value for DIU and Time to Live.

See this for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/managed-virtual-network-private-endpoint#time-to-live-preview